# Fusion Middleware Consol - hostname in URL

Tags: weblogic12c, hostname

I try to display Fusion Middleware Consol (WebLogic 12c) in my browse according to pattern:

```
http://hostname.domain:port/em
```

The port is **7001**, the name of domain is **domains** but I can't find hostname in config.xml file. If hostname should be the hostname of the computer it doesn't work for me. Where I find the hostname?

EDIT:

Snippet from my config.xml:

```
<name>domains</name>
  <domain-version>12.2.1.2.0</domain-version>
   (...)

 <server>
    <name>myAdminServerName</name>
    <ssl>
      <name>myAdminServerName</name>
      <listen-port>7002</listen-port>
    </ssl>
    <machine>wls_machine_1</machine>
    <listen-address>127.0.0.1</listen-address>
  </server>
```

If I run admin console in this addres: `http://127.0.0.1:7001/console` it works. But if I try run Fusion Middleware Consol in this URL: `http://127.0.0.1.domains:7001/em` or `http://127.0.0.1.domains:7002/em`it doesn't work.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

By default, weblogic listens on every available address. But if you change the listening address setting, you would find it between the `<listen-address></listen-address>` tags

```
<server>
    <name>myserver</name>
    <listen-port-enabled>true</listen-port-enabled>
    <listen-address>localhost</listen-address>
  </server>
```

Comment: I've edited my post. Could you take a look at my config.xml snippet, I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it still doesn't work.